# How to measure execution time of this dinning philosopher program(python)?

Tags: python

```
from __future__ import print_function
from threading import Semaphore, Lock, Thread
from time import sleep
from random import random
import argparse
from timeit import Timer

(THINKING, EATING) = (0, 1) #philosopher states

def left_fork(id):
    return id

def right_fork(id):
    return (id+1) % NUM_PHILOSOPHER

def right(id):
    return (id+1) % NUM_PHILOSOPHER

def left(id):
    return (id+NUM_PHILOSOPHER-1) % NUM_PHILOSOPHER

def get_fork(id):
    global mutex
    global tstate
    global sem

    mutex.acquire()
    tstate[id] = 'hungry'
    test(id)
    mutex.release()
    sem[id].acquire()

def put_fork(id):
    global mutex
    global tstate
    global sem

    mutex.acquire()
    tstate[id] = 'thinking'
    test(right(id))
    test(left(id))
    mutex.release()

def test(id):
    global tstate
    if tstate[id] == 'hungry' and tstate[left(id)] != 'eating' and tstate[right(id)] != 'eating':   
        tstate[id] = 'eating'
        sem[id].release()

def philosophize_footman(id,meal):
    global forks
    global footman
    state = THINKING
    for i in range(meal):
        sleep(random())
        if(state == THINKING):
            msg = "Philosopher " + str(id) + " is thinking."
            #print(msg)
            footman.acquire()
            forks[right_fork(id)].acquire()
            forks[left_fork(id)].acquire()
            state = EATING
        else:
            msg = "Philosopher " + str(id) + " is eating."
            #print(msg)
            forks[right_fork(id)].release()
            forks[left_fork(id)].release()
            state = THINKING
            footman.release()
    print("Finish philosophize_footman")

def philosophize_lefthand(id,meal):
    global forks
    state = THINKING
    for i in range(meal):
        sleep(random())
        if(state == THINKING):
            #define the left hand user.
            if(id == 3):
                forks[left_fork(id)].acquire()
                forks[right_fork(id)].acquire()
                state = EATING
            else:
                forks[right_fork(id)].acquire()
                forks[left_fork(id)].acquire()
                state = EATING
        else:
            if(id == 3):
                forks[left_fork(id)].release()
                forks[right_fork(id)].release()
                state == THINKING   
            else:
                forks[right_fork(id)].release()
                forks[left_fork(id)].release()
                state == THINKING
    print("Finish philosophize_lefthand")

def philosophize_Tanenbaum(id,meal):
    for i in range(meal):
        get_fork(id)
        sleep(random())
        put_fork(id)
    print("Finish philosophize_Tanenbaum")

def run_c(numP,numM):
    for m in range(numP):
        phil1 = Thread(target = philosophize_Tanenbaum,args = (m,numM))
        phil1.start()

def run_a():
    global NUM_PHILOSOPHER
    global MEAL
    for i in range(NUM_PHILOSOPHER):
        phil = Thread(target = philosophize_footman, args = (i,MEAL))
        phil.start()

def run_b(numP,numM):
    for n in range(numP):
        phil2 = Thread(target = philosophize_lefthand, args = (n,numM))
        phil2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Philosopher dining')
    parser.add_argument('--nphi','-n',
                        type = int,
                        default = 5,
                        help = 'add num_phi',
                        metavar = 'number of philosophers')
    parser.add_argument('--meal','-m',
                        type = int,
                        default = 100,
                        help = 'number of meals',
                        metavar = 'meal')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    NUM_PHILOSOPHER = args.nphi #define number fo philosophers
    MEAL = args.meal    #define number of meals
    forks = [Semaphore(1) for i in range(NUM_PHILOSOPHER)]  #defines forks
    sem = [Semaphore(0) for i in range(NUM_PHILOSOPHER)]    #semaphores
    footman = Semaphore(4) #limit the number of philosophers
    mutex = Semaphore(1)    #mutex
    tstate = ['thinking'] * NUM_PHILOSOPHER #T-states

    run_a()
#   run_b(args.nphi,args.meal)
#   run_c(args.nphi,args.meal)
    timer = Timer(run_a)
    print("Time:{:0.3f}s".format(timer. timeit(100)/100))
```

It is dinning philosopher problem solution by python. The code is listed above. I want to measure the running time of function run_a(). But when using timer, I found it doesn't work well. It prints the time result immediately(e.g 0.001s, but the code is still running.) So please help me with it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the threads to finish; call [`Thread.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) on each thread:

```
def run_a():
    global NUM_PHILOSOPHER
    global MEAL
    threads = []
    for i in range(NUM_PHILOSOPHER):
        phil = Thread(target = philosophize_footman, args = (i,MEAL))
        phil.start()
        threads.append(phil)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

The `Thread.join()` method blocks until the thread has completed, or you can specify a timeout.

Comment: Hi Martijin, I tried your method. But I found I cannot get execution time. The result: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "philosophers.py", line 153, in <module>
    print("Time:{:0.3f}s".format(timer. timeit(100)/100))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 195, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 100, in inner
    _func()
  File "philosophers.py", line 120, in run_a
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 667, in join
    self.__block.wait()

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything, I am afraid.